# Customizing contour labels in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a contour plot. I want to make some changes in the contour labels. I want them to place along each contour in white color. Here is my code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_] := x + y^-1;
p = ContourPlot[
f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
Contours -> 10,
ContourLabels -> True,
LabelStyle -> {Directive[Bold, Medium], White, 
RotateLabel -> True},
ImageSize -> Large
]
```

The output of this code is

[image]

but I want something like this

[image]

How can I figure it out? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pure function with a [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text) object as the [`ContourLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourLabels) option setting. The fourth argument of [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text) specifies the direction, which can be computed with:

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y^-1
t[x_, y_] = Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] . {{0, -1}, {1, 0}};
```

Then:

```
ContourPlot[
    f[x, y],
    {x,-5,5},
    {y,-5,5},
    Contours->10,
    ContourLabels->Function[{x,y,z},Text[z,{x,y},{0,0},t[x,y], BaseStyle->FontColor->White]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: To make the contour labels more readable (i.e., no upside down contour labels), I've added in the 'function t2[z_] := If[z[[1]] < 0 && z[[2]] < 0, -z, If[z[[1]] < 0, {-z[[1]], z[[2]]}, z]]` and replaced `t[x, y]` with `t2[t[x, y]]`.  Is there a better way?  (Is this a separate question?)

Comment: After looking at this a bit more just using `Sign[t[x, y][[1]]] t[x, y]` in place of `t[x, y]` seems to do the trick.