# Labeling contours

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to label several contours in one graph. First, I drew three lines `1 == ii3 + (1 + ss)/2`, `0 == ii3 + (1 + ss)/2`, and `1 == ii3 + (1 + ss)/2}` with `ContourPlot` and used `ContourLabels` to add labels:

```
ContourPlot[{-1 == ii3 + (1 + ss)/2, 0 == ii3 + (1 + ss)/2, 
  1 == ii3 + (1 + ss)/2}, {ss, -2, 0}, {ii3, -1, 1}, Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {S, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(3\)]\)"},
  ContourLabels -> {"Q=-1", "Q=0", "Q=1"}]
```

[image]

It does not show labels at all. How can I get the labels of each contours?

I know that I can get a similar figure with:

```
Plot[{-(1 + ss)/2 - 1, -(1 + ss)/2, 1 - (1 + ss)/2}, {ss, -2, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {S, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(3\)]\)"}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"Q=-1", "Q=0", "Q=-1"}]
```

[image]

However, there are many curves that can be drawn with `ContourPlot` but cannot be drawn with `Plot`. Is there any way to add labels in `Contourplot`?

Comment: See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199567/customizing-contour-labels-in-contourplot), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143892/custom-labeling-of-contours-in-contourplot), and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255602/how-to-draw-several-contours-label-in-separate-colors)

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

ContourPlot[ii3 + (1 + ss)/2,
 {ss, -2, 0}, {ii3, -1, 1},
 Contours -> {-1, 0, 1},
 ContourShading -> None,
 Frame -> False,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesOrigin -> {-0.5, 0},
 AxesLabel -> {S, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(3\)]\)"},
 ContourLabels -> (Text[
     StringForm["``\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``", HoldForm[Q], #3],
     {#1, #2}, 1.1 Sign[#1 + 1] {1, 1},
     Background -> White] &),
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]